# Transform velocities from one frame to an other within a rigid body

Tags: reference-frames, coordinate-systems, rigid-body-dynamics

I come from non-physics background but just came to face the following problem. I have a rigid body with two attached frames of reference A and A'.

I know:

- the rotation and translation between A and A'
- the instantaneous translational velocities V$_x$, V$_y$, V$_z$ along the axes of A
- the instantaneous angular velocities $\omega_x$, $\omega_y$, $\omega_z$ around the axes of A

Based on the assumption that A and A' are attached to the same rigid body I want to compute:

- the instantaneous translational velocities V$_x$', V$_y$', V$_z$' along the axes of A'
- the instantaneous angular velocities $\omega_x$', $\omega_y$', $\omega_z$' around the axes of A'

[image]

---

The context is that I have a robot and I know it's instantaneous velocities in the frame of reference of it's sensor, but would like to know the instantaneous velocities at some other point of the rigidly attached body.

Comment: You should find plenty of similar examples in textbooks. Did you try some literature or internet search?

Comment: I spend quite some time on internet research, but either I don't know what really to search for, or all literature that I found required more preliminaries than I can muster. I would be thankful for pointing me at some example/literature/search query that would allow me to solve this problem.

Comment: for the velocity: the physical quantity is the same, as they are connected rigidly. $v = \sum e_i v_i = \sum e_i' v_i'$ assuming the $e_i, e_i'$ are orthonormal this gives $v_i' = e_i' \sum e_i v_i$

Comment: You can always make the transformation to Principal Axis coordinates. Build the transformations $U_{A}$ and $U_{A'}$. The total transformation matrix from A to A' is given by $U_{A} U_{A'}^{\dagger}$

Comment: @Bort Isn't that incorrect since the velocity of each particle will also depend on angular velocity of the rigid body in inertial frame?

Answer (score 2):

I think that what you want to achieve is described in the following lecture: [Robotics, Geometry and Control - Rigid body motion and geometry](http://www.eeci-institute.eu/pdf/M5-textes/M5_slides4.pdf) by Ravi Banavar.

You know the homogeneous transformation matrix that transforms the coordinate of a point in the frame A to the coordinate of the same point in the frame A' (using the same notation as in the lecture):

$ \bar{q}_{A'} = \begin{pmatrix}
q_{A'}\\ 
1
\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}
R_{A'A} & p_{A'A} \\ 
0 & 1
\end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix}
q_{A} \\ 
1
\end{pmatrix} = \bar{g}_{A'A} \bar{q}_{A} $

with $ R $ the rotation matrix and $ p $ the translation vector.

The translational and angular velocities in the frame A' should be:

$ \begin{pmatrix}
v_{A'} \\ 
\omega_{A'}
\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}
R_{A'A} & \hat{p}_{A'A}R_{A'A} \\ 
0 & R_{A'A}
\end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix}
v_{A} \\ 
\omega_{A}
\end{pmatrix} $

With:

$ a = \begin{pmatrix}
a_1 & a_2 & a_3
\end{pmatrix}^T $

and the skew-symmetric matrix: 
$ \hat{a} = \begin{pmatrix}
0 & -a_3 & a_2 \\ 
a_3 & 0 & -a_1 \\ 
-a_2 & a_1 & 0
\end{pmatrix} $